# paste special by value with destination vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to paste special by values the data to my destination. I am not able to work it out. Please can someone help. thank you

```
Sub ExtractData()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim erow As Long
Dim i As Long
'Dim mydate As Date
Dim myVIN As String

lastrow = Worksheets("Page1_1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Page1_1").Select

Worksheets("Page1_1").Range("L1").Select

For i = 2 To lastrow

myVIN = Cells(i, 1)


If myVIN <> "#N/A" Then

erow = Worksheets("OASIS Lookup").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(i, 12).copy Destination:=Sheets("OASIS Lookup").Cells(erow, 1)
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: `If myVIN <> "#N/A" Then` - if the cell actually contains an error, that will fail. You could use `If Not Application.IsNA` to actually test... Or just use `Range.AutoFilter` and filter out error cells.

Comment: This is my mistake, I am actually looking for error cells. I should have changed it to look for error cells. What do you recommend in that instance? I am a novice with VBA. Thank you

Comment: `If IsError(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then`. Though `Range.AutoFilter` should be a lot faster here than looping.

Comment: `Cells(i, 12).copy` would be one line `Sheets("OASIS Lookup").Cells(erow, 1).pastespecial...` would be a line by itself.

Answer (score 1):

### 'Assign' Instead of `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

- Avoid `Select` and any flavor of `Active`.
- Use variables.
- So what if the code is longer, but you will still be able to understand it in a week, a month or even a year. The code will not run faster if it has fewer lines.
- Use comments to describe what the code is doing. Not so many as I did but more moderately.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractData()
    
    ' Define workbook and worksheets.
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Page1_1")
    ' Define Source Last Row.
    Dim srcRow As Long
    srcRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets("OASIS Lookup")
    ' Define Target Current Row.
    Dim tgtRow As Long
    tgtRow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Write values from Source Worksheet to Target Worksheet.
    
    ' Declare a variable to hold each value in Criteria Column (1).
    Dim myVIN As Variant ' Only 'Variant' can accept any value, incl. errors.
    ' Declare Source Worksheet Rows Counter.
    Dim i As Long
    ' Loop through rows of Source Worksheet.
    For i = 2 To srcRow
        ' Write value in current row of Criteria Column (1) to 'myVIN'.
        myVIN = src.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ' Check if 'myVIN' does not contain an error value.
        If Not IsError(myVIN) Then
            ' Increase Target Current Row.
            tgtRow = tgtRow + 1
            ' Write value in current row of Source Column (12) to current row
            ' of Target Column (1).
            tgt.Cells(tgtRow, 1).Value = src.Cells(i, 12).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Inform user.
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple solution could be to replace this line

```
Cells(i, 12).copy Destination:=Sheets("OASIS Lookup").Cells(erow, 1)
```

by

```
Cells(i, 12).copy 
Sheets("OASIS Lookup").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```